# SQL Server - any equivalent of Excel's CHOOSE function?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'd be surprised if this hasn't been asked before, but I haven't been able to find anything.  Excel has a function

```
CHOOSE(n, x_1, x_2, x_3, ...)
```

which returns x_n for the given value of n.

Is there anything similar in SQL (either standard or MS-specific) supported by SQL Server 2008?  I know it should really be implemented using a lookup table in the database, but for what I'm doing I'm not able to add new tables to the database.

I could create a temporary table and populate it from the SQL script, or use

```
CASE n WHEN 1 THEN x_1 WHEN 2 THEN x_2 WHEN 3 THEN x_3 ... END
```

but is there anything less cumbersome?

Comment: I am not aware of one, up to and including SQL 2008 R2. If you find one I would be interested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortuantely, no it seems not to be the present in your version.

The [`CHOOSE`-Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213019%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) is only available since SQL Server 2012 and works quite the same as you describe the Excel-function.

Answer (score 2):

*"but for what I'm doing I'm not able to add new tables to the database"*. Well you always can use temporary table, table variable or, if it's really one time thing - derived table:

```
select
    ...,
    l.v
from <your table> as t
    left outer join (values
        (1, x_1), (2, x_2), (3, x_3)
    ) as l(n, v) on l.n = t.n
```

Of course, you can always try to create your own `choose()` function:

```
create function dbo.f_Choose5(
    @index int,
    @value1 sql_variant,
    @value2 sql_variant,
    @value3 sql_variant,
    @value4 sql_variant,
    @value5 sql_variant
)
returns sql_variant
as
begin
    return (
        case @index
            when 1 then @value1
            when 2 then @value2
            when 3 then @value3
            when 4 then @value4
            when 5 then @value5
        end
    )
end

select dbo.f_Choose5(3, 1, 2 ,3, 4, 5)
select dbo.f_Choose5(3, 1, 2 ,3, default, default)
```

but you have to keep in mind that scalar functions are not really optimized in SQL Server.